# VBA obtaining values from a workbook and put them in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having trouble putting values from one workbook to another.

Right now it works, but as you can probably see in the code below, it constantly opens one workbook after the second one until the loop ends. So my question: how can I do this without opening the workbooks all the time?

Code:

```
For i = 2 To LastRow
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("...")
With Worksheets("...")
    x = .Cells(i, 2).Value
    y = .Cells(i, 3).Value
End With

If variable1 = variable2 Then
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("...")
With Worksheets("...")        
    .Cells(i, 2).Value = x
    .Cells(i, 3).Value = y    
End With
End If

Next i
```

The following code gives me an error: Subscript out of range at `x = wb2.WorkSheets("...").Cells(i, 2).Value`

```
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("...")
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("...")
For i = 2 To LastRow
    x = wb2.WorkSheets("...").Cells(i, 2).Value
    y = wb2.WorkSheets("...").Cells(i, 3).Value
If variable1 = variable2 Then
    wb.WorkSheets("...").Cells(i, 2).Value = x
    wb.WorkSheets("...").Cells(i, 3).Value = y
End If

Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

How about like this, first set the `wb` and `wb2` objects outside the loop, and after just set the values directly between workbook.

```
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("...")
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("...")

For i = 2 To LastRow
    wb.Worksheets("...").Cells(i, 2).Value = wb2.Worksheets("...").Cells(i, 2).Value
    wb.Worksheets("...").Cells(i, 3).Value = wb2.Worksheets("...").Cells(i, 3).Value
Next i
```

Comment: When I try this I get a subscript out of range error, I edited my question with this part. Also I need to store the values of x and y so I can't do it completely like u proposed.

Comment: @Stan are trying to copy whole columns ? and also store them in array called `x` and `y` ?

Comment: No I don't want to copy whole columns. Only rows with a specific value in column A.

Comment: @Stan and where is that part of the code ? Where is the `If` criteria ?

Comment: Updated my code. I didn't want to put too much code in my question to keep my question specified to where the problem is.